# Problems with expect script when detached from terminal

Tags: background, cron, expect, tty

I am trying to run a bash script, that invokes expect, as a daemon and everything is fine as long as the script remains attached to a terminal. But when I move the script to background or execute it from crontab, the spawned telnet proces does not communicate with the expect script anymore, a time-out error appears on debug, and the script fails.

Another thing worth mentioning is the fact that I am having this problem only with some devices that have an older firmware version, (upgrade is costly and not an option) same script on newer device runs perfectly.

Any feedback on how to overcome this issue would be very appreciated.

debug output as below:

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d
set argc 0
set argv0 "/usr/bin/expect"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {9602}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n ****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n ****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *\r\n *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *\r\n *      / /      | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *\r\n *     / /       | |     | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *\r\n *    / /        | |     |  ____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *\r\n *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *\r\n *  / /____      | |     | |_____      |  |       /  /   \  \   *" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n ****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *\r\n *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *\r\n *      / /      | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *\r\n *     / /       | |     | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *\r\n *    / /        | |     |  ____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *\r\n *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *\r\n *  / /____      | |     | |_____      |  |       /  /   \  \   *\r\n * /_______|     |_|     |_______|     |__|      /__/     \__\  *\r\n *                                                              *\r\n *                        Welcome  to  you !!!                  *\r\n *                                                              *\r\n *                        ( MSG5200  V2.0.3 )                   *\r\n ****************************************************************\r\nLogin:" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Login:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Login:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n ****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *\r\n *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *\r\n *      / /      | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *\r\n *     / /       | |     | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *\r\n *    / /        | |     |  ____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *\r\n *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *\r\n *  / /____      | |     | |_____      |  |       /  /   \  \   *\r\n * /_______|     |_|     |_______|     |__|      /__/     \__\  *\r\n *                                                              *\r\n *                        Welcome  to  you !!!                  *\r\n *                                                              *\r\n *                        ( MSG5200  V2.0.3 )                   *\r\n ****************************************************************\r\nLogin:"
send: sending "root\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? no

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "root\r" to { exp6 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# ' is '*# '. Activating booster.

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)\r" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)\r                                      \roPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no
expect: timed out
send: sending "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r" to { exp6 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# ' is '*# '. Activating booster.

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)\r                                      \roPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)\r                                      \roPress any key to continue (Q to quit)\r" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)\r                                      \roPress any key to continue (Q to quit)\r                                      \rhPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no
expect: timed out
send: sending "logout\r" to { exp6 }
expect: timed out
```

**debug output when script run from terminal:**

```
expect version 5.45 argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d set argc 0 set argv0 "/usr/bin/expect" set argv "" executing commands from command file parent: waiting for sync byte parent: telling child to go ahead parent: now unsynchronized from child spawn: returns {14876}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to TI-ATEM-KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to TI-ATEM-KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n
****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to TI-ATEM-KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n
****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *\r\n *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *\r\n *    / /      | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *\r\n *     / /       | |     | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *\r\n *    / /  | |     |  ____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *\r\n *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to TI-ATEM-KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n
****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *\r\n *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *\r\n *    / /      | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *\r\n *     / /       | |     | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *\r\n *    / /  | |     |  ____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *\r\n *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *\r\n *  / /____      | | | |_____      |  |       /  /   \  \   *" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login:"? no

expect: does "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to TI-ATEM-KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n
****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *\r\n *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *\r\n *    / /      | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *\r\n *     / /       | |     | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *\r\n *    / /  | |     |  ____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *\r\n *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *\r\n *  / /____      | | | |_____      |  |       /  /   \  \   *\r\n * /_______|     |_|     |_______|     |__|      /__/     \__\  *\r\n *                        
*\r\n *                        Welcome  to  you !!!                  *\r\n *                                                              *\r\n *                        ( MSG5200  V2.0.3 )                   *\r\n ****************************************************************\r\nLogin:" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Login:"? yes expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Login:" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7" expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Trying 10.102.0.37...\r\r\nConnected to TI-ATEM-KASH.\r\r\nEscape character is '^]'.\r\r\n
****************************************************************\r\n *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *\r\n *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *\r\n *    / /      | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *\r\n *     / /       | |     | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *\r\n *    / /  | |     |  ____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *\r\n *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *\r\n *  / /____      | | | |_____      |  |       /  /   \  \   *\r\n * /_______|     |_|     |_______|     |__|      /__/     \__\  *\r\n *                        
*\r\n *                        Welcome  to  you !!!                  *\r\n *                                                              *\r\n *                        ( MSG5200  V2.0.3 )                   *\r\n ****************************************************************\r\nLogin:" send: sending "root\r" to { exp7 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Password:"? no

expect: does "root\r\nPassword:" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Password:"? yes expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Password:" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7" expect: set expect_out(buffer) "root\r\nPassword:" send: sending "root\r" to { exp7 } Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# ' is '*# '. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "\r\n\r\nTIR-ATEM-KASH# " (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=yes re=yes expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\r\n\r\nTIR-ATEM-KASH# " expect: set expect_out(1,string) "TIR-ATEM-KASH" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7" expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n\r\nTIR-ATEM-KASH# " send: sending "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r" to { exp7 } Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# ' is '*# '. Activating booster.

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "s" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName           : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType            : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile   : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap            : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :          \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName           : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType            : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile   : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap            : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :          \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\nxdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: " (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName           : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType            : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile   : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap            : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :          \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\nxdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: 0/0(kbps) \r\ndownstream retrans-ctrl : disable        \r\nupstream retrans-ctrl   : " (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName           : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType            : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile   : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap            : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :          \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\nxdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: 0/0(kbps) \r\ndownstream retrans-ctrl : disable        \r\nupstream retrans-ctrl   : disable        \r\n" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName           : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType            : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile   : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap            : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :          \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\nxdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: 0/0(kbps) \r\ndownstream retrans-ctrl : disable        \r\nupstream retrans-ctrl   : disable        \r\nTIR-ATEM-KASH" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

expect: does "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName           : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType            : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile   : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap            : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :          \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\nxdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: 0/0(kbps) \r\ndownstream retrans-ctrl : disable        \r\nupstream retrans-ctrl   : disable        \r\nTIR-ATEM-KASH# " (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=yes re=yes expect: set expect_out(0,string) "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName            : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType       : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile         : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap        : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :    \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\nxdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: 0/0(kbps) \r\ndownstream retrans-ctrl : disable        \r\nupstream retrans-ctrl   : disable        \r\nTIR-ATEM-KASH# " expect: set expect_out(1,string) "TIR-ATEM-KASH" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7" expect: set expect_out(buffer) "show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config\r\nportName            : VDSL_2/4/13    \r\nportType       : vdsl      \r\nbaseprofile         : VBASEDEF.PRF   \r\nserviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\ndpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF   \r\nupboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF   \r\nalarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF    \r\nActiveState         : active         \r\ndslLinkState        : down      \r\nlinktrap        : inform         \r\ndata-path-mode config: ptm            \r\ndata-path-mode actual: ptm            \r\nlastestLinkUptime   :    \r\nlastestLinkDowntime :          \r\nxdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: 0/0(kbps) \r\ndownstream retrans-ctrl : disable        \r\nupstream retrans-ctrl   : disable        \r\nTIR-ATEM-KASH# " send: sending "logout\r" to { exp7 } expect: read eof expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7" expect: set expect_out(buffer) "logout\r\nConnection closed by foreign host.\r\r\n" spawn telnet TI-ATEM-KASH 1123 Trying 10.102.0.37... Connected to TI-ATEM-KASH. Escape character is '^]'. 
****************************************************************  *   _______  _________   _______       __       __  __     __  *  *  |____  / |___   ___| |  _____| ____|  |____  \ \ \ \   / /  *  *      / /     | |     | |      |  __    __  |  \_\ \_\ /_/   *  *     / /       | |  | |_____ | |_ |  |__| |   _________    *  *    / /        | |     | 
____| |____    ____|  |_________|   *  *   / /         | |     | |           |  |        __    __     *  *  / /____      | |     | |_____      |  | /  /   \  \   *  * /_______|     |_|     |_______|     |__|      /__/  \__\  *  *                                                            
*  *                        Welcome  to  you !!!                  *  *                                                              *  *                        ( MSG5200  V2.0.3 )                   *  **************************************************************** Login:root Password:

TIR-ATEM-KASH# show vdsl2 port 2/4/13 line-config portName            : VDSL_2/4/13 portType            : vdsl baseprofile         : VBASEDEF.PRF serviceprofile      : VDEFVAL.PRF dpboprofile         : VDPBODEF.PRF upboprofile         : VUPBODEF.PRF alarmprofile        : VDEFVAL.PRF ActiveState         : active dslLinkState        : down linktrap            : inform data-path-mode config: ptm data-path-mode actual: ptm lastestLinkUptime   : lastestLinkDowntime : xdsl2ChStatusActDataRate: 0/0(kbps) downstream retrans-ctrl : disable upstream retrans-ctrl   : disable TIR-ATEM-KASH# logout Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Note: I was not able to run the script using expect , but the following bash script works great

```
#!/bin/bash

host=$1
port=$2
user=$3
pass=$4
uport=$5
cmd1='show vlan port '${uport}
cmd2='logout'
( echo open ${host}  ${port}
sleep 0.1
echo ${user}
sleep 0.1
echo ${pass}
sleep 0.1
echo ${cmd1}
sleep 0.1
echo ${cmd2}
sleep 0.1
 ) | telnet
```

Comment: `expect` stops getting data from `telnet` entirely? This is a problem running *on* the older firmware or running with `telnet` connecting *to* machines with the older firmware?

Comment: It stops at login, username is not being send, connection times out

Comment: Yes, I have this problem only on devices with older firmware

Comment: You run the `expect` script *on* an older device and `expect` doesn't send the login to some *other* device? Or you run the `expect` script on machine A and when it connects to an older device it doesn't send the username?

Comment: I have the script on a Linux server, fedora21, and I am trying to telnet from this machine to different network devices to complete some configuration tasks.

Comment: Ok. And when connecting to the older devices the script doesn't send the login? Or the login doesn't work? Have you turned on expect debugging to see what (if anything) it is actually getting when it connects to those machines as opposed to the working ones? Have you looked at the network traffic?

Comment: ****************************************************************\r\nLogin:"
send: sending "root\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? no

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Password:"? no
expect: timed out
send: sending "root\r" to { exp6 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '.*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# ' is '*# '. Activating booster.

expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match regular expression ".*[^-A-Za-z0-9_]([-A-Za-z0-9_]*)# "? Gate "*# "? gate=no

Comment: the username does not get sent, and I receive this "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" the spawned telnet session continues to remain active. also, the same script when run from terminal works as expected

Comment: Update the post with the debugging output so you can format it sanely.

Comment: I added the debugging output, thnx a lot

Comment: That's sending the username it looks like. Are the older firmware machines slower? Does increasing the `expect` timeout help? What is the expect debugging output from the bit around seeing `Login:` and sending the username look like on a working system? What about when this is attached to the terminal?

Comment: I have tried with different timeouts, no change, I am adding to the post the debug output when script is attached to the terminal.
what I suspect is expect does not control the telnet session any more, but i dont know how to "force" it to do so, have tried using script command to exec the script on cron, have tried fork and disconnect within expect script, nothing is working, dont know what to do any more...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving you a "Password:" prompt, you're being told to "Press any key to continue (Q to quit)". Probably what happens after that is unknown, but if I was developing this, I'd assume that you get the password prompt afterwards, so you want something like

```
expect {
    "Press any key to continue (Q to quit)" {send \r; exp_continue}
    "Password:" {send "$password\r"}
}
```

The `exp_continue` command basically loops back to the same expect command, so you're still waiting for one of those patterns.

Keep watching the debug output so you can see what happens.

Comment: tried this, still not working

below the debug results
expect: does "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Press any key to continue (Q to quit)"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Press any key to continue (Q to quit)"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "rPress any key to continue (Q to quit)"
send: sending "\r" to { exp6 }
expect: continuing expect
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Press any key to continue (Q to quit)"? no
"Password:"? no

Comment: it sends back an empty string, and if I modify the script to expect and continue that, it enters into a loop
expect {
    "" {exp_send \r; exp_continue}
    "Press any key to continue (Q to quit)" {exp_send \r; exp_continue}
    "Password:" {exp_send $passwd\r}
}

Comment: Everything works fine, I get the prompt and am able to send commands. The script works even when I run it from command line. The problem occurs only when the script is run detached from a terminal, such as with nohup in background, or from crontab, or when called from a php function. I can see the telnet session being still open when expect script times out. The only thing I can think of is expect loosing control over spawned telnet session.